# use flatedecode filter when embed javascript in PDF, using php FPDF

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, fpdf

I want to create a dynamic PDF file with javascript embedded, using php code form this link:

http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script36.php

but the javascript is plain text in the PDF file, is there any way to add 'flatedcode' filter to the javascript code, and use it as PDF stream object, so that there's no plain text javascript code presented in the final PDF file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though not exactly with the code you point to. The code creates a dictionary with a "JS" element as a text string.

If you read the PDF reference you'll see that this "JS" element can be either a text string or text stream. As it can be a text stream it could get a FlateDecode filter. Should you would have to modify the code to create not a string but a stream and to encode the stream with Flate.

I do hope you realize that the use of automatically executed Javascript on document open may simply not work and could be very obnoxious (to say the least).

Comment: Thanks David for the tip! i will look into it.